# Details on prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

So I'm coming from Python and trying to wrap my head around what a prototype is. Is there anyway I could get a Pythonic description of a Prototype? It kind of sounds like a descriptor had a baby with **init**. Also, I heard that Prototype tends to have negative consequences when being used on the DOM. Is that true? If so, why? Thanks, I've been looking through a ton of articles and the Prototype just isn't making sense to me at this point!

Comment: I suppose _a Pythonic description of a prototype_ would be [`prototype.py`](https://github.com/airportyh/prototype.py), but this is an implementation of prototypes into _Python_. _Prototypical languages_ go about code reuse in a different way to the classical _Class_, it's not a simple translation.

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks, a quick google of prototype.py took me to a very helpful site and it sounds like a wasn't terribly far off. Correct me if I'm wrong but you're able to define variables and set default values (like init). Additionally, you can add custom functions similar to a partial or using a decorator or override built in functions like print (similar to descriptors ability to override __getattr__)?

Comment: I was also trying to find some insight on this for a while, and stumbled on this article http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/. Hope it helps.

Comment: You have an _Object_ `obj`, if you _SET_ a property on `obj` then it will be set as an _own_ property (even if it already exists, as long as it's not already setter). If you _GET_ a property _k_ of `obj`, `let e = obj;` **X** if `e` has it's own _k_, return that. If it doesn't, `let e = Object.getPrototypeOf(e);`, go back to **X**.   ----   Multiple _Objects_ can inherit from the same _prototype chain_, so if you perform a set on an _Object_ that's not at the bottom level then everything that inherits from it will see this change even after they've been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, much like Python, everything is an object. This includes functions.

Javascript doesn't have classes though. However, you can use functions to simulate the behavior of classes.

---

All functions have a property called `prototype`.
If you say:

```
myInstance = new myFunction()
```

`myFunction` is run. (So it acts like a constructor) and the result is stored in `myInstance`. Nothing crazy here, but what that `new` keyword does is copy the `prototype` property from `myFunction` over to an internal property of `myInstance`. This property is referred to in the docs as `[[prototype]]` and you can reference it in some modern browsers as `__proto__`. `__proto__` is not standardized though, so its use is discouraged.

If you need to get the `[[prototype]]` of an object, rather than using `__proto__` use `Object.getProtoTypeOf(myInstance)`.

```
MyClass.prototype == Object.getPrototypeOf(myInstance) //true
```

---

When you call a method on an object, if the object doesn't have that method, Javascript will look in its `[[prototype]]` property. It will keep searching the prototype (a.k.a. inheritance) chain until it reaches `Object`.

So as an example:

```
function MyClass() {
  this.prop ="hello"

  //Javascript implicitly returns `this` when the function is invoked using "new"
} 

MyClass.prototype.instanceMethodOne = function() {
  console.log(this.prop);
}

var myInstance = new MyClass();

myInsance.instanceMethodOne(); //"hello"
```

In the above example, `myInstance` will have a property called `prop`. But it will have no property called `instanceMethodOne`. This property was added to `MyClass`'s prototype object. However, a reference to this object was copied to that `[[prototype]]` (a.k.a) `__proto__` property of `myInstance`, so it is accessible.

You now have a situation where all instances have their own state, which is created in the constructor function (just a normal function) but they share the state that was added to the function's prototype property. This is how you get "classes" in Javascript.

Comment: It's not good to call these things classes, call them _Constructors_

Comment: Going over constructors to explain JavaScript prototypes... Maybe not the best idea.

Comment: @Kyll What would be a better way to explain them? Some overly complex metaphor about an object's blueprints? ;) Please feel free to add your own answer. I will happily up vote it. This is just my way of explaining it and it is technically accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is starting to come together. JS is just such a confusing language. In an article linked above new isn't recommended but then I see the author using the new keyword later in the article -.-

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 `new` is really just a shortcut for `Object.create()`, which is more powerful because it allows you to assign any object you want to be the prototype of another object. If you want to make one class inherit from another class, you create the prototype of the child class manually via `ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.protoype)` That introduces some slight caveats though, best explained in the tutorials: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance

Comment: @Kyll Awesome, I've been trying to get a concise answer. An, hopefully last question here. How frequently is Prototype used? It sounds like a very powerful tool but maybe too powerful for its own good. As I read about Prototype I see a lot of complaints that it doesn't play nice with other libraries and frameworks since you run the risk of overriding a default behavior another framework or library depended upon.